# jquery - Finding the href attribute of a jquery multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I was wondering, assuming you have a multiple selector as below:

```
$('.BOO li', '.FOO li a').click(function() {

});
```

and you want to find the `href` value of both classes, using the `this` keyword, how do you achieve that?

Because if you go ahead and do it like below,

```
$('.BOO li', '.FOO li a').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href");
   //do stuff
    });
```

`.BOO li` is obviously left out.

Is there a way to target the `this` of only the `.BOO1 li` and find it's `a`?

Additional info:- of course, an alternative would've been selecting the `.BOO1 li a` directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$('.BOO li', '.FOO li a').click(function() {
    var href;
    if($(this).attr("href"))
        href = $(this).attr("href");
    else
        href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Here is a more concise, but more confusing way to do the above:

```
$('.BOO li', '.FOO li a').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href") ? $(this).attr("href") : $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: you sir deserve a grammy award! Amazing! Simply Amaaaaaaazing!! lol XD

Answer (score 2):

Use `.each` to iterate over each selected element and in the callback function use `$(this).attr("href")` to get your value.